# Div next to image

Tags: html, css

I'm teaching `<div>` and i have problem. Div is under image, but I want next to. I tried with setting float, position but nothing help.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqqUV/2/) (here divs/images are unconnected!)

How to change it to connect images and form on up?

Comment: sorry, but could you change your fiddle to a minimum of code and items? i can't see the problem right now

Comment: sry i forgot to make this. new version http://jsfiddle.net/aqqUV/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divs automatically create a line break, because they are block elements. Try using `display: inline-block` on the div.

I updated your fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/aqqUV/3/

Note the code change here:

```
<div class="form" style="
    margin-left: 70px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
">
```

Comment: This help with display form next to image, but divs are unconnected.

Comment: Obvious, but it still messes up in alignment. I would rewrite the whole setup of divs to use relative positions.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean "unconnected", but if you want them to be in one line, you can use display: inline-block also for the sub-divs, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/aqqUV/4/ oh and note that the whitespaces between them are caused by linebreaks in your HTML

Comment: Ok, I updated it again: http://jsfiddle.net/aqqUV/5/ You just have to assign the same width and height to the divs too. Of course the layout isn't yet right, but i think you get the point ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just give first image a width and

```
display:inline-block;
float: left;
```

and then give these proerties to div following image

```
display:inline:block;
float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try giving the first div a width and let it float left.
the folowing div elements should float next to it, but don't forget to clear:both at the end!