# CSS text next to image in div

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to place inside my div next to the image some text with a white background but I can't figure out how I am able to do this.

This is the curren state: https://gyazo.com/06e2a1306212047184b8da1a70debbf8
And I want to have it like this: https://gyazo.com/e892693d5390cdd20cc62dd5c2e96b45

I am a starting coder so Im new in this world :D

Over here my code:

```css
div.gallery {
    border: 10px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}

div.gallery1 {
    border: 5px solid #2f354e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #17c;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 10px solid #17c;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    display:block
    
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="../MarkRutte/faq.html"></a>
      <img src="../MarkRutte/css/backgrounds/MarkRutteportret.jpg">
    </a>
            <div class="desc">Mark Rutte</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989535/div-next-to-image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> A flex container expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow. Most importantly, the flexbox layout is direction-agnostic as opposed to the regular layouts (block which is vertically-based and inline which is horizontally-based).

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 10px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

div.gallery1 {
  border: 5px solid #2f354e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #17c;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 10px solid #17c;
}

.gallery-header {
  display: flex;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block
}

.gallery-text {
  padding: 15px;
}

.desc {
  background: #2f354e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-header">
      <a href="../MarkRutte/faq.html">
        <img src="../MarkRutte/css/backgrounds/MarkRutteportret.jpg">
      </a>
      <div class="gallery-text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">Mark Rutte</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of just saying try this, explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @Dejan.S You need solution or explanation?

Comment: Please add some explanation for your solution

Comment: I don't, but maybe other people that are new to programming are most likely to need. Questions get asked because we have problems with something, some like to learn rather than just copy paste and don't know what to do next time it happens. Other might have the similar issue, if they can read an explination rather then looking at something they find hard to begin with makes it so much easier. But hey if you can't spend a few minutes to explain that is fine. You know that we can flag answers as low quality, your answer is exatcly why there is that option.

Comment: @Dejan.S Edited the solution

Comment: Not good enough if you ask me. What does it give somebody fresh to this?