# how to put img next to div?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put my img right next to the div. But it has always been either below or above the div. How can I do that?
Thank you!

```css
html {
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #edc9b5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

.menu,
.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
  </div>
  <center>
    <img src="/images/tree.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Div next to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989535/div-next-to-image)

Comment: `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both the current div and the image in a div which has the following CSS properties:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

Basically:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
  <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
</div>
<center>
<img src="/images/tree.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
</center>
</div>


.wrapper{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```css
html {
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #edc9b5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

.menu,
.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<div class="menu">
  <div>
    <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/2fz1zlPNq7cj7QkLAtKdqYrKvs0=/3704x2778/smart/filters:no_upscale()/the-difference-between-trees-and-shrubs-3269804-hero-a4000090f0714f59a8ec6201ad250d90.jpg" alt="tree image">

</html>
```

Comment: I Appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

First you have include this thing into wrap to do that replace your html with this

```
   <div class="wrap"> 
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
    </div>
    <center>
    <img src="/images/tree.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
    </center>
   </div>
```

then after that add this thing to your css file

```
    html{image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    background-color: antiquewhite;}
    
    h1 {padding: 20px;
        font-family: fantasy;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;}
    
    .menu{display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-around;
          background-color: #edc9b5;
          width: 150px;
          height: 300px;}
    
    .item{margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
          font-size: 25px;
          color:black;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Comic Sans MS;}
    
    .menu, .item{border-radius: 10px;}
    
    img{width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        float: center;}
    .wrap{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       }

so I hope it works
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer in any way?

Comment: I had the same problem when I was learning flexbox and I implement where to do this thing on his own code.Because sometimes get confuse with these things.